# Handle postthreadmessage() inside a thread which is blocking in while(1) loop or use "Event Driven Sockets"

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I have a single server multiple client udp application. There is a single thread (thread#1) with a single socket (socket#1) to receive data from client#1 continuously. The task of this receiving thread is to continuously receive data at its socket.

I have a button which says "Send data to Client#1" on Server application GUI. When this button is pressed, I want my receiveing thread to suspend reception and send some data on socket#1 and when data is sent, continuous reception is resumed.

How can this be done? If I even postthreadmessage() when button is presses, the receiving thread has no check for these posted messages since it is always inside the while loop receiving messages. How can it check for posted message corresponding to buttons pressed?

**EDIT: Another Suggestion**

What if I make my socket "Event Driven"? i.e. whenever there is some data available at socket to be read, FD_READ event is generated and I can read on socket, and whenever I want to write some data on the socket, I GENERATE AN EVENT FD_WanttoWrite and then data is written on the socket. Is something similar to this possible?

(I know about FD_READ but I am not sure about FD_WanttoWrite when I wish to write something on Socket)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to pause your reading thread.  Just `send/to()` the data immediately from inside the button Click handler using the same socket (or even a different socket, since UDP is connectionless).

The only real reason to pause your reading thread would be if the sent data receives a response that you do not want your receiving thread to see.  If that is the case, then you have a few choices:

1. have the receiving thread pass any responses to the button Click handler for processing when needed.
2. add a flag to the receiving thread that tells it to stop reading from the socket.  Have the button set the flag while sending, then clear the flag when finished.  Have the receiving thread's loop use `select()` with a small timeout so each iteration of the loop can check the flag and skip reading if the flag is set.
3. switch to an event-driven socket and use a message loop in the receiving thread, like you suggested.  Then you can pass messages to the thread, such as a message to tell it to skip reading when FD_READ messages arrive, and another message to resume reading.  If you want the thread to call `send/to()` on the button's behalf, you can also have a message for that, and any reading will be implicitly blocked while sending is in progress.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion. First of all, I want my receieve thread to be suspended when sending is going on because there is one single socket that both send and receive thread wil use so in order to avoid any synchronization issues, I want only one thread to use socket at a time.

Comment: I want to go with choice#3 that you provided but I am not sure how to generate events when I want to

Comment: Sockets are bi-directional and thread safe. One thread can read from a socket while another thread writes to the same socket at the same time without needing to synchronize them.

Comment: Yes, you do, because you said it yourself - `PostThreadMessage()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from another thread (ie: Gui or new background thread different from your receive thread).  You'll need access to the socket, so you may need to tweak its scope.

Comment: So you mean I must have a separate thread for send()ing and the socket must be same for sending as used for receiving?

Comment: Look at the other suggestion I added in my Question. Is that possible?

Comment: Like Remy said...UDP sockets are connectionless...all you need is the IP address and port number your client is listening to and you can make a new socket and sendto with that one...but the caveat there is if the client replies and uses the address from the recvfrom call, its going to go to the servers new socket and not the one your using in your servers receive loop.

Comment: If you have no reason to "stop reading" in your receive loop when sending (I'm having a hard time trying to envision why you would) then I don't see why you would need an event driven approach